# Web API response is different between Blazor Server and WebAssembly

Tags: telerik, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I am attempting to apply the Telerik Blazor-UI FileManager "Flat data" demo, [text](https://demos.telerik.com/blazor-ui/filemanager/flat-data), to a Blazor Server and a standalone WebAssembly application with a Web API using the .NET 7 templates.  To compare apples to apples, I have created a razor class library so the code is identical between hosting models starting at MainLayout.

The FileManager works great in Blazor Server, but does not show the folder contents using Blazor WebAssembly.  The only difference I have found is in the deserialized JSON response.  When inspecting the locale Data variable, a List, there is a sublevel of items when using Webassembly.  Whereas Blazor Server gives you the list at the top level without having to drop down into items.  I get the same result using Newtonsoft JSON for deseriialization.  See code block and attached images.

Telerik Technical Support says it is a deserilaization issue and "not a component-related issue."  What is causing the difference in behavior.  Will this impact the resulting list object that is passed to components?  And how do you get the same list structure?

I have also notice the View option is not available in WebAssembly when inspecting the local responseBody variable so I can't use the JSON Visualizer.  Is this inherent in using 2022 Community Edition or something else?

Call to API

```
public class FileBrowserApiRepository<FlatFileEntry> : IFileBrowserApiRepository<FlatFileEntry>
{
    string _controllerName;
    string _rootPath;
    HttpClient _http;    JsonSerializerOptions jsonOptions = new(JsonSerializerDefaults.Web)
    {
        WriteIndented = true,
        PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
    };

    public async Task<List<FlatFileEntry>> ReadDirectoryAsync(string rootPath)
    {
        try
        {
            if (rootPath != null)
            {
                var url = $"{_controllerName}/ReadDirectoryAsync/{rootPath}";
                var result = await _http.GetAsync(url);
                result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string responseBody = await _http.GetStringAsync(url);
                var response = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<FlatFileEntry>>(responseBody, jsonOptions);
                // Newtonsoft JSON
                string responseBody2 = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var response2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FlatFileEntry>>(responseBody2);
                if (result!.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return response;
                }
                else
                {
                    var _data = new List<FlatFileEntry>();
                    return _data;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var _data = new List<FlatFileEntry>();
                return _data;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var msg = ex.Message;
            var _data = new List<FlatFileEntry>();
            return _data;
        }
    }
}

[![Server Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWFa6.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWFa6.png)

[![Client Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgQI5.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgQI5.png)

Thanks!

I have also tried the below methods with identical results.
```

// Abreviated Method
string responseBody2 = await _http.GetStringAsync(url);
var response2 = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List>(responseBody2, jsonOptions);

// Newtonsoft JSON Method
string responseBody3 = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var response3 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List>(responseBody3);